# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime [Remove Time from DateTime]

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date, datetime

I'm retrieving  a date from my sql server which is 2016-01-06(year-month-day) into a string. The sql format is Date. Instead of getting 2016-01-06 only, I will get 1/6/2016/(month/day/year) 12:00:00 AM . Now what I'm trying to do is remove the time and convert the date in dd/M/yyyy format. I've followed all the example in the other questions but I will get "*String was not recognized as a valid DateTime*" Is there any steps I missed or I'm doing it wrongly.

```
 protected void btnUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string Name = cmbName.Text;
                string start = "";

                SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;" + "Initial Catalog=IBBTS_DB; Integrated Security =SSPI");

                    SqlCommand retrieveStart_DateCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT startDate FROM testSet where TS_ID = 121 ;", myConn);
                    SqlDataReader reader6 = retrieveStart_DateCmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader6.Read())
                    {
                        start = (reader6.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    }
                    reader6.Close();  

                    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


             }
        }
```

Comment: why you not try to use Convert function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Stores the `datetime` data type dates in a standard format for SQL. However when you retrieve a `datetime` data type from SQL the `datetime` result will be converted to the `DateTime` struct in C#.

As the retrieved value IS a `DateTime` object you dont need to convert to a string then parse it out. Doing this doubles the conversion work for retreiving that `datetime`.

Try this example.

```
protected void btnUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            string Name = cmbName.Text;
            DateTime start = default(DateTime);

            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;" + "Initial Catalog=IBBTS_DB; Integrated Security =SSPI");

                SqlCommand retrieveStart_DateCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT startDate FROM testSet where TS_ID = 121 ;", myConn);
                SqlDataReader reader6 = retrieveStart_DateCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader6.Read())
                {
                    start = (DateTime)reader6[0];
                }
                reader6.Close();  
                string myFormattedString = start.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that the field is going to be a date, and it's just the one field, can you just use GetDateTime?

```
DateTime dateTime = Reader6.GetDateTime(0)
```

That might let you skip string conversions. Obviously, check for dbNull's first if that's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `ToString()` - you are dumbing down the type that SQL Server is sending you.  You should be able to retrieve the value using `GetDateTime(0)` instead of `GateValue(0)`.  That will allow you to manipulate the value more easily.

C# does not come with a built-in `Date` type, only `DateTime`.  Hence this is what you are presented with.  Having gotten a `DateTime`, you can use the normal Format operations to format it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning date in this format:

```
protected void btnUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
        string Name = cmbName.Text, start = string.empty;

        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;" + "Initial Catalog=IBBTS_DB; Integrated Security =SSPI");

        SqlCommand retrieveStart_DateCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT startDate FROM testSet where TS_ID = 121 ;", myConn);
        SqlDataReader reader6 = retrieveStart_DateCmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader6.Read())
        {
              start = (reader6.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
        reader6.Close();  

        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//DateTime.ParseExact(start, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
}
```

And in your Web.config file under  add this

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
         <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
    </system.web>
```